# mail_to address in seed database (Rails 5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailto, link-to, targeting

I have an item in a set of show profiles pages that gives an email from a seeded database:

```
  <h4><%= @admin.email %></h4>
```

Which needs to be converted into a mail_to tag, similar to this : `<p><%= mail_to 'info@db.com', "info@db.com" %>` What I came up with looks like this:

```
<% @admin.each do |agent| %>
  <h4<%= mail_to <%= agent.email %>, "<%= agent.email %>" %></h4>
<%end%>
```

But it's crashing, with the error `syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
'.freeze;      end
                  ^`

Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't be just the values? `<%= mail_to agent.email, agent.email %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove unnecessary `<%%>` symbols:

```
<% @admin.each do |agent| %>
  <h4><%= mail_to agent.email, agent.email %></h4>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I get `undefined method `each'` from that.

Comment: If `@admin` is single object, not a relation or array, just use `<h4><%= mail_to @admin.email, @admin.email %></h4>`

Comment: Got it! Thank you!